# Resizeable columns in TreeTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexigrid, treetable

I'm using [Ludo's great TreeTable plugin](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable), but I'm trying to figure out how to make 'resizeable columns' -- meaning the user can grab the border in the table head / row, then shift them to alter the size of the columns.

I found one thing out there that does something similiar -- [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableResizable.jsf;jsessionid=1rr3n5rnjclq2jezmimkuy71w)  -- however it's written heavy in java, and doesn't jive with the the pure JS solution I think this should be.

Does anyone know of an attainable way to do this? I tried combining [flexigrid](https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid) with treetable but that turned out to be pretty insanely difficult (and maybe fruitless) solution.

Answer (score 1):

For all of its down sides, ExtJS does tables/trees very well.

[ExtJS 4.2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/)

Comment: Ah, this would be good but it's non-free. Are there any free version that are like this?

Comment: [ExtJS | OpenSource version](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/) - I hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your help! I was really looking for a way to integrate it into treetable, and ExtJS is too free to use (GNU). However, it is a good point of reference. Thanks!